# How to pass arguments array to another function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I have a function in JavaScript:

```
function test() {
  console.log(arguments.length);
}
```

if I call it with `test(1,3,5)`, it prints out `3` because there are 3 arguments. How do I call test from within another function and pass the other function's arguments?

```
function other() {
  test(arguments); // always prints 1
  test(); // always prints 0
}
```

I want to call `other` and have it call `test` with its `arguments` array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at `apply()`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

```
function other(){
    test.apply(null, arguments);
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `test.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: "if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed." But yeah, it will work either way. `this` only needs to be used when you actually want to pass it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try passing the arguments like this?

```
function other() {
  var testing=new Array('hello','world');
  test(testing); 
}
function test(example) {
  console.log(example[0] + " " + example[1]);
}
```

Output: `hello world`

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Waclock/jRVsc/4/):

Comment: I think the OP just wants to know how to pass dynamic parameters to other functions without hardcoding

Comment: And if the test function to be called was made by the other package or encapsulated, he just wants to pass the same params into that function.